# Is there a way to open a VS Code extension tab if it isn't open?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

We have a treeview in our VS Code extension which can be toggled on and off by the user by calling a command. However if the user toggles the treeview on and they don't have the remote explorer open (where the treeview is displayed), it looks like the command doesn't do anything. Is there a way to say, open the remote explorer if it isn't open, and focus on the treeview when the treeview is toggled on so the user can see the command showed a new treeview?

Answer (score 0):

Closing since I found there is a way to do exactly this with the "TreeView.reveal(TreeItem)" method